# Why AJAX response is not in sortable manner

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sorttable.js

I am using `sorttable.js`for table sorting and my table is updated in every 3 sec by ajax response but the response is not in sorted manner as i expect it to be.

**Index page**

```
 <div id="resDiv">
            <table id="myTable1" class="sortable">
            <thead>
                <tr><th id="person">Person</th><th id="monpay">Monthly pay</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>Jan Molby</td><td>£12,000</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Steve Nicol</td><td>£8,500</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Steve McMahon</td><td>£9,200</td></tr>
                <tr><td>John Barnes</td><td>£15,300</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr><td>TOTAL</td><td>£45,000</td></tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        </div>
         <a href="#" id="ajax-append">Append new table data</a>
```

**ajax response is :**

```
<table id="myTable" class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Person</th><th>Monthly pay</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>prabha Molby</td><td>£12,000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>abcd Nicol</td><td>£8,500</td></tr>
        <tr><td>steev McMahon</td><td>£9,200</td></tr>
        <tr><td>John Barnes</td><td>£15,300</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td>TOTAL</td><td>£55,000</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $(function() {

                $("#ajax-append").click(function() {
                    setInterval(function() {
                    var request = $.get("assets/replacecontent.jsp", function(html) {
                        alert(html);
                        $('#resDiv').html(html);
                        var newTableObject = document.getElementById("myTable");
                        alert(newTableObject);
                        sorttable.makeSortable(newTableObject);

//                        alert($("#myTable").length);

                    });
                }, 3000);

                });
            });
```

Now if any time i sort the ajax response it get sorted but after another response it again change it's order but i want it sorted as previous one.

Comment: Well, you replace the sorted table with a new, unsorted one. What else did you expect?

Comment: @Bergi but i used the `makeSortable()` method to sort the new table in my js

Comment: The method name `makeSortable` sounds as if it makes the new table sortable, but does not sort it. It wouldn't know the sorting criteria of the previous table anyway.

Comment: @Bergi what i read from this [link](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/#ajaxtables) that this method sort the table

Comment: Hm, then the wording on that page is confusing. See http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/#externalcall and @AlexanderKludt's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have read what the sorttable.js faq says:

> **Sorting the table when the page is loaded**
>
> Lots of people ask, "how do I make sorttable sort the table the first
>   time the page is loaded?" The answer is: you don't. Sorttable is about
>   changing the HTML that is served from your server without a page
>   refresh. When the page is first served from the server, you have to
>   incur the wait for it to be served anyway. So, if you want the table
>   sorted when a page is first displayed, serve the table in sorted
>   order. Tables often come out of a database; get the data from the
>   database in a sorted order with an ORDER BY clause in your SQL. Any
>   solution which involves you running sorttable as soon as the page
>   loads (i.e., without user input) is a wrong solution.

But they also state a [solution for that](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/#externalcall):

```
//Find the TH you want to use, maybe you can store that using an event handler before
var myTH = document.getElementsByTagName("th")[0];
//Then sort it
sorttable.innerSortFunction.apply(myTH, []);
```

But to that you will have to find the column your user clicked on before, and to be honest I have not found any way using the sorttable api directly. Maybe use some kind of click event handler and store the th that was clicked last.