# Sortable HTML table with Powershell

Tags: html, powershell

Is it possible with the script below to create a sortable HTML table without using JavaScript? All of the examples I have found so far require the use of JavaScript. If possible I would like it to be purely done in PowerShell.

```
#Set variables
$image = "C:\Scriptrepository\NHSI(left).gif"
$ConvertImage = [Convert]::ToBase64String((Get-Content $image -Encoding Byte))
$ImageHTML = "<img src=data:image/gif;base64,$($ConvertImage) alt=NHSI/>"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date -Format F

#Function for alternating table colour rows
Function Global:Set-AlternatingRows {
                [CmdletBinding()]
                Param(
                [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
                [string]$Line,

                [Parameter(Mandatory)]
                [string]$CSSEvenClass,

                [Parameter(Mandatory)]
                [string]$CSSOddClass
                )
    Begin {
                $ClassName = $CSSEvenClass
        }
    Process {
                If ($Line.Contains("<tr><td>"))
                {   $Line = $Line.Replace("<tr>","<tr class=""$ClassName"">")
                If ($ClassName -eq $CSSEvenClass)
                {   $ClassName = $CSSOddClass
}
                Else
                {   $ClassName = $CSSEvenClass
            }
        }
    Return $Line
    }
}    

#Function to validate request and create variable from input
Function Global:GetADGroupMembersrecursively {
    Write-Host "Enter Distribution List / AD Group name:" -ForegroundColor Green
    $Global:ADGroupName = Read-Host
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ADGroupName))
    { 
    CLS
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor red "Cannot be blank, please re-enter AD Group / distribution list name" | Out-Null
    GetADGroupMembersRecursively 
    }
    $Global:DLCheck = DSQuery group -Name "$ADGroupName"
    if ($DLCheck -eq $null) 
    { 
    CLS
    Write-Host -foregroundcolor red "Did not find AD Group / Distribution List, please verify this is the correct name" | Out-Null
    GetADGroupMembersRecursively
  }
}

GetADGroupMembersRecursively

$Head = @"
<style>
BODY {font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt; color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff;}
TABLE{margin: auto; font-family: Segoe UI; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #4C607B; width: 100%;height :50px;}
TH, TD {border: 1px solid #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse;padding: 3px;}
TH {font-size: 1.2em; background-color: #003366; color: #ffffff; }
TD {color: #000000; }
 .even { background-color: #efefef; }
 .odd { background-color: #c0c0c0; }
TR { background: #b8d1f3; }"
H4 {font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: #4C607B;align=right;}
H5 {font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt; color: #4C607B;align=right;}
</style>
"@ 

#Table creation
$Post = "<br><br> Members of $ADGroupName <br> Generated on $CurrentDate"
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroupName -Recursive | Get-ADUser -pr GivenName,Surname,mail,sAMAccountName | Select-Object @{Name = "First Name"; Expression = {$_.GivenName}}, @{Name = "Last Name"; Expression = {$_.Surname}}, @{Name = "Email Address"; Expression = {$_.mail}}, @{Name = "User Account"; Expression = {$_.sAMAccountName}} | sort Surname | 
ConvertTo-HTML -head $head -body $ImageHTML -PostContent $Post -As Table | Set-AlternatingRows -CSSOddClass odd -CSSEvenClass even | Out-File C:\ScriptRepository\Results\$ADGroupName.htm
Invoke-Item C:\ScriptRepository\Results\$ADGroupName.htm
```

Comment: Sortable? Do you mean that you want someone to be able to interact with the HTML you generate and sort a table on one of its columns?

Comment: Hi Matt, yes, I would like it if they would be able to click a column title to sort the contents by that column.

Comment: Ok then. Did you mean without Java or with Java*Script*? Also does the answer have to be HTML. I mean you could use `Out-GridView` which would do most of this for you. Moot if this is going to be read by people that don't use PowerShell. Could you not just do something like [this from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sort_table_desc) ....  yes i know its javascript? I don't know what you have that exclusion.

Comment: Hi Matt, yes without JavaScript, HTML is required by the end user.

Comment: _I'm_ going to say that it cannot be done with that restriction as I am not aware of any CSS/HTML magic that would allow this. Why can't you use javascript? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948578/how-can-i-make-an-html-table-sortable-with-javascript-without-loading-data-via-a suggests jquery which is still javascript reliant

Comment: I have got it working with js however the desk that will be running these queries is restricted and I was not able to run the query as them, hence my request to use purely powershell

Comment: _however the desk that will be running these queries is restricted and I was not able to run the query as them_ So JavaScript is disabled on those systems? As stupid as this may sound perhaps include multiple tables where the content is sorted differently.

Comment: There isn't a way to do it in pure HTML that I know of. If you want dynamic content, then you likely need to use something more dynamic than HTML.

Comment: Yes it is disabled,unfortunately I can only have one report. Our night guy will create reports on AD groups like domain admin and other high level groups to post on a Website checking, some of the groups are very large, this is where the ability to sort would be very handy, but if it cant be done, it cant be done. Thank you for your time Matt.

Comment: I'd agree that no JS means no sorting.

Comment: You could use a menu, with multiple html pages (all static), with a different sorting in each, for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible with the script below to create a sortable HTML table without using JavaScript?

No. This is not possible with that limitation or at least not with current HTML. You *might* be able to do something with vbscript in the page but I would not be surprised if that is off limits to you as well.

The only thing I could think to do within the confines you have laid out is to roll out separate reports, within the same html file, that show the *preferred* sorting options and not necessarily *all* sorting options.

Something else you could do or do in conjunction is create a CSV file. That way your recipients could read in the data into a program or even a text editor like NotePad++ and have it do the sorting for you. I understand if that is not within the scope of your task but it is still a valid option in general.

> If possible I would like it to be purely done in PowerShell.

Another option that might be "out there" is that instead of HTML output you could use something like `Out-GridView`. That will provide an interactive interface to your data. If the users are the ones running the script then this option would be available to them.