# Fixed <thead> in <table>

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<table border="1" style="height:50px; overflow:auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1
      </th>
      <th>Col 2
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 3
      </td>
      <td>Cell 4
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 5
      </td>
      <td>Cell 6
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd like the above table to be of 50px height so the scrollers would kick in when the content grows, but I'd also like table headers (thead) to be fixed always on top, while other content can be scrollable. Is there an solution, preferable using jQuery?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this post: [jQuery Scrollable, Sortable, Filterable table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192608/jquery-scrollable-sortable-filterable-table)

It looks like they've got what you need (which is a freezable, scrollable jquery table).

Answer (score 6):

Found myself in need of similar functionality. Couldn't find anything light and simple, so I created the plugin myself: [TH Float jQuery Plugin](http://rommelsantor.com/clog/2011/03/03/th-float-jquery-plugin-fixed-thead-tfoot-table/)

I hope someone finds it useful.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is my trick. You have to change something in your html too.

The trick consists in inserting through js after the real scrolling thead, a secondary and identical thead positioned fixed. Cells widths are adjusted through js too.

Adjust the code on your needs.

**CSS**

```
thead.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="overflow: auto;">
  <table id="my_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Head 1</th>
        <th>Head 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Body 1</td>
        <td>Body 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( function() {
  fixListThead();
});
$(window).resize( function() {
  fixListThead();
});
var fixListThead = function() {
  $('#my_table thead.fixed').remove(); // Removes (if present) fixed thead when resizing
  var widths = [];
  $('#my_table thead th').each( function(i, element) {
    widths[i] = $(element).width();
  });
  $('<thead class="fixed">' + $('#my_table thead').html() + '</thead>').insertAfter($('#my_table thead'));
  $('#my_table thead.fixed th').each( function(i, element) {
    $(element).css('width', widths[i] + 'px');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="width: 300px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <td>Column 1</td>
  <td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div style="overflow: auto;height: 50px; width: 320px;">
  <table style="width: 300px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Update**:

Check this out:

[Link](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html)

[Another Link a t CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/66-table-styling-2-fixed-header-and-highlighting/)

Comment: erm..thats kinda nasty, because column widths won't match unless specified manually. Honestly, I've tried this once and regretted.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS transform may be more simple:

```
-webkit-transform','translateY(0px)'
```

Answer (score 0):

these days browser begin to well suport the css directive position:sticky, who is the css answer to this problem, it mus be applyed to each  and you don't need to specify a height for the table for it to work.

```
<style>
table th{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px; /* pixel gap between the top and the head when it stop scrolling
}
</style>
<table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Col 1
          </th>
          <th>Col 2
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 3
          </td>
          <td>Cell 4
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 5
          </td>
          <td>Cell 6
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```