# how to make table scrollable with fixed headings

Tags: jquery, html, css

Does anyone know how to make the table below scrollable as well as being able to keep the table heading fixed so it doesn't scroll down with the table?

Below is html and jquery

```
 <table id="qandatbl">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="answer">Answer</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>


    function insertQuestion(form) {   


        var $tbody = $("<tbody></tbody>");
        var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer'></tr>");
        var $answer = $("<table class='answer'></table>");

    var $this, i=0, $row, $cell;
    $('#optionAndAnswer .answers').each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        if(i%7 == 0) {
            $row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($answer);
            $cell = $("<td/>").appendTo($row);
        }

        var $newBtn = $("<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='display:%s;' onclick='btnclick(this);' />".replace('%s',$this.is(':visible')?'inline-block':'none')).attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class'));


        $newBtn.appendTo($cell);

        i++;
    });

        $tbody.append($tr); 
        $tr.append($answer);
        $('#qandatbl').append($tbody);

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965976/fixed-thead-in-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/TGBym/

Make appropriate changes as per your requirements

Answer (score 0):

[Chris Coyer](http://css-tricks.com) has a really nice video tutorial on how to do exactly this.

Check it out here: http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/66-table-styling-2-fixed-header-and-highlighting/

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are needing a Jquery Plugin; for example:

http://www.datatables.net/index

or

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid

there are many, but I think these are the best