# How to make the table-head of a table in a div with scrollbar to be fixed? (both horizontal AND vertical scrolling)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Situation:**

1. I have a div with scrollbar: (`overflow: auto;`)
2. In this div I have a table with a table-head
3. When I scroll through the table-body, the header is not visible (like when you scroll through a website window)

**What I want:**

When the user will scroll through my table, the table-header should have position fixed.

Simple position fixed ( `<thead  style="position:fixed;">`) did not help, since the table header is like 50 cells wide so you have to scroll right/left to see all the cells.

I absolutely dont know where to start, any ideas will be appreciated.

**Found answers**

I found lots of similar problems on stack overflow, but none of them explicitly told me how to apply the fixed header to be scrollable horizontaly in the div.

http://jsfiddle.net/TGBym/44/ -> a fidle by Dhaval Shukla from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888526/how-to-make-table-scrollable-with-fixed-headings), but doesnt seem to be checking on the horizontal scrolling..

Comment: try this: http://fixed-header-using-jquery.blogspot.in/2009/05/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-and.html

Comment: You could just put the table header into a different table that is fixed. Would that be an option?

Comment: Max: no, because I use a table-filter plugin on the table, in some headers which makes it's own headers, if none specified..

Comment: @Max: actually got back to the problem after seven months and used your solution. Cheers! :)